# SSRS date expression tweak

Tags: ssrs-2012

In SSRS I am currently using this expression:

**=IIF(Today() >= DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1),DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1), DateSerial(Year(Today()) - 1, 4, 1))**

In a date parameter (default values, specify values). This gives me **01/04/2018**.

However for one particular report it would be helpful for the date to default to the previous year - e.g. **01/04/2017**.

I've tried to tweak the above expression to make this work, but haven't succeeded. Can this expression be changed to go back one year?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IIF(Today() >= DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1),DateSerial(Year(Today())-1, 4, 1), DateSerial(Year(Today())- 2, 4, 1))